# Apache beam GroupByKey duplicate events

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a apache beam pipeline in java that looks like this:

```
        pipeline
        .apply("Read pubsub",PubsubIO.readStrings()
                .fromTopic(inputTopic)
        )
        .apply(window)
        .apply(ParDo.of(new OrderCodeKey()))
        .apply(GroupByKey.<String, RawBsonDocument>create())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new GetLastOrder()))
        .apply(ParDo.of(new ShopIDKey()))
        .apply(GroupByKey.create())
        .apply(ParDo.of(new CountShopOrder()))
        ;
```

Problem description: **I need to stream events of orders from a pubsub topic, each event is of type "update" or "insert" and corresponding to an update/insert operation in mongodb for an order**. In each event there are some notable fields:

- clusterTime -> the time at which the operation happens
- order_code -> order's code
- shop_id -> the shop which the order belongs to.

My goal is to **compute the total orders per shop.**

Detail of pipeline:

- Read from pubsub topic
- Create key-value pair (for subsequent GroupByKey) key is order code and value is the document

```
  public static class OrderCodeKey extends DoFn<String, KV<String, RawBsonDocument>>{
       @ProcessElement
       public void processElement (@Element String order, OutputReceiver<KV<String, RawBsonDocument>> out) throws ParseException {
           // Parse JSON
           RawBsonDocument document = RawBsonDocument.parse(order);
           BsonDocument fullDocument = document.getDocument("fullDocument");
           String orderCode = fullDocument.getString("order_code").getValue();
           //Integer orderCode = 0;
           out.output(KV.of(orderCode, document));
       }
   }
```

- GroupByKey (group by order_code)
- Combine events with same order_code to get the latest order (the one with the biggest clusterTime)

```
public static class GetLastOrder extends DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<RawBsonDocument>>, KV<String, BsonDocument>>{
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement (@Element KV<String, Iterable<RawBsonDocument>> orders, OutputReceiver<KV<String, BsonDocument>> out) throws ParseException, java.text.ParseException {
            List<RawBsonDocument> docs = Lists.newArrayList(orders.getValue());
            Collections.sort(docs, new Comparator<RawBsonDocument>(){
                @Override
                public int compare(RawBsonDocument o1, RawBsonDocument o2) {
                    BsonTimestamp t1 = o1.get("clusterTime").asTimestamp();
                    BsonTimestamp t2 = o2.get("clusterTime").asTimestamp();
                    return t2.compareTo(t1); // sort desc
                }
            });
            RawBsonDocument document = docs.iterator().next();
            out.output(KV.of(orders.getKey(), document.getDocument("fullDocument")));
        }
```

- Create new key (key= shop_id) for subsequent GroupByKey

```
public static class ShopIDKey extends DoFn<KV<String, BsonDocument>, KV<Long, BsonDocument>>{
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement (@Element KV<String, BsonDocument> order, OutputReceiver<KV<Long, BsonDocument>> out) throws ParseException {
        Long shopId =  Long.valueOf(order.getValue().getInt32("shop_id").getValue());
        out.output(KV.of(shopId, order.getValue()));
        }
    }
```

- GroupByKey (group by shop_id)
- Count number of orders per shop

```
public static class CountShopOrder extends DoFn<KV<Long, Iterable<BsonDocument>>, Shop>{
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement (@Element KV<Long, Iterable<BsonDocument>> orders, OutputReceiver<Shop> out) throws ParseException, java.text.ParseException {
            List<BsonDocument> docs = Lists.newArrayList(orders.getValue());
            Long countOrder = Long.valueOf(docs.size());
        }
    }
```

In the last step, **I assume that the input Iterable orders will contain only unique  orders** (because after the GroupByKey-GetLastOrder, only the latest event is kept). However, When I debug I received **events with the same order_code** - which I have already reduced by GetLastOrder ParDo. Here is the window and trigger I use:

```
Window<String> window = Window.<String>into(
                FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(60))
                )
                .triggering(
                        AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                        .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane())
                )
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardSeconds(0))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes();
```

I would appreciate any comment/help on this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need intermediate results but just want hourly summary of unique orders per shop, early triggering is unnecessary.

When you use `.withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane())`, each pane will process only a subset of data after the first data is arrived in the pane. With `.accumulatingFiredPanes()`, you will see the accumulated result from the previous pane, so the same data appear multiple times across the different panes for the same window.

Please see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#setting-a-trigger for the details.

Comment: Hi ihji, thanks for your answer
Yes I don't need the intermediate results but I also want the
result to be recalculated every time a new order appear (new event pushed
to pubsub)

I understand that `.accumulatingFiredPanes()` make the 
last stage (CountShopOrder) to receive multiple event with the same order_code

Is there anyway to **only take the latest result of a pane** ?